# Amazon S3 Signed URL and Cloudfront - Access Denied

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am creating a `signed url` using the following:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = my_access_key
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = my_secret_access_key
    KEYPAIR_ID = my_keypair_id
    KEYPAIR_FILE = path_to_keypair_file
    CF_DISTRIBUTION_ID = cf_dist_id
    my_connection = cloudfront.CloudFrontConnection(
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    )


    distro_summary = my_connection.get_all_distributions()[0]
    distro_info = my_connection.get_distribution_info(distro_summary.id)
    distro = distro_summary.get_distribution()    

    SECS = 8000
    signed_url = distro.create_signed_url(
                    "https://%s/%s" % (distro_info.domain_name, 'restaurant_1_banner.png'),
                    KEYPAIR_ID,
                    expire_time=time.time() + SECS,
                    valid_after_time=None,
                    ip_address=None,
                    policy_url=None,
                    private_key_file=KEYPAIR_FILE
                    #private_key_string=KEYPAIR_ID
                    )


    return signed_url
```

This returns a url like: "https://d1yllqv1oc7n6x.cloudfront.net/restaurant_1_banner.png?Expires=1426681326.67&Signature=Nsvyl-EowDRGuw-MfdgS34C6bsHKKC2L88ROfPBRAnsbpoeYfpJj6NQaTj4PGiG02Z7PRqkk5F0cBWKOik738H8xrlQQf8CuS0AouisnqMvZ4FLx94fSMo8vwFDg9jKLTMB1T0AGjWvgAcDlkLo4nYxyHQ077pwp3Do8g1eP62QD-~Ys4kejtVGtPTx6O1pM4gRLsmM8Kn7HJ618Hp4XMgRWwqJaCL-2C0YQP1PdEMbSOS6ZrmGTN~U5T-s-PZX1poS6qRiY4-Ma66DVLgmOTBh5vqjCWEqsbKZKFWFufsA2mMa4ON11yBUSyIbGJPpgKdRLU0pZuo7RX3~sIe6Q9w__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAISF4B35DSGOUTGTQ"

When I click on this link, I get the message:

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access denied</Message>
</Error>
```

This is my `bucket policy` for my `s3` `bucket`.

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E3I8A03QRR3ASO"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::menumaster/*"
    }
]
}
```

Please let me know if any additional information is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my bucket policy.

```
    {
        "Version": "2008-10-17",
        "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "1",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity EH238ELEGANOC"
                },
                "Action": "s3:GetObject",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::onur.deneme/*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

This is the distribution :
di53i9yykewl5.cloudfront.net

Restrict Bucket Access : Yes

Origin Access Identity : Use an Existing Identity

Restrict Viewer Access(Use Signed URLs) : Yes
Trusted Signers : Self

There should be no other ACL or policy.

Comment: Thanks Osalkk! This seems to have fixed the issue. I was missing: `Restrict Viewer Access(Use Signed URLs) : Yes Trusted Signers : Self`

Comment: Why not use the `Trusted key groups` option and generate a key group?

Answer (score 0):

Is the "Restrict Bucket Access" selected as "yes" and "origin access identity" selected?

Can you try the code below that I used before?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time,boto,rsa
from boto import cloudfront
from boto.cloudfront import distribution

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="your access key"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="your secret access key"


conn = boto.cloudfront.CloudFrontConnection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
dist = conn.get_all_distributions()
a=dist[0].get_distribution()
#Set parameters for URL
key_pair_id = "your key pair id" #cloudfront security key
priv_key_file = "xxxxxxxxx.pem" #cloudfront private keypair file
expires = int(time.time()) + 60 #1 min
url="http://dbvvi2cumi6nj.cloudfront.net/santa.png"
signed_url = a.create_signed_url(url, key_pair_id, expires,private_key_file=priv_key_file)
print signed_url
```

Comment: Thanks for this Osalkk, however, I am encountering the same problem. I have selected `Restrict Bucket Access`. For `Origin Access Identity` I selected `Use an Existing Identity`.

Comment: About the broken image ,If you inspect the element , what does it say?

Comment: In terms of the `elements`, it loads an `img` tag in the `body`. However, I noticed something strange with the network calls. I'm getting a `HTTP 304 Not Modified` and the `size` of the image is only `334B` when it should be close to `500KB`.

Comment: Also I can't view my `image` in `S3` as I get an `access denied` message. Is this normal?

Comment: Currently the `ACL` for my `bucket` is just my default `username`. All 4 permissions (List, Upload/Delete, View Permissions and Edit Permissions) have been granted.  The `object` permissions are also set for the `default username`. All permissions (Open/Download, View Permissions and Edit Permissions) have been granted.

Comment: Hey @Osalkk! I think the last part about `Use an Existing Identity Restrict Viewer Access(Use Signed URLs) : Yes Trusted Signers : Self` fixed it! Let me just test it a bit and I'll get back to you. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can visit my blog to use signed-urls also [link][http://www.wekanban.com/amazon-web-services-cloudfront-signedurls]

Comment: Cool, I hope it's fixed.