# How can I enforce a S3 policy to let only signed URL get objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I can generate my signed urls the AWS-SDK node package, and I could confirm they work when my bucket is set as public.

However, I can't find where I can set the parameters mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29119394/amazon-s3-signed-url-and-cloudfront-access-denied):

> Restrict Bucket Access : Yes
>
> Origin Access Identity : Use an Existing Identity
>
> Restrict Viewer Access(Use Signed URLs) : Yes
>
> Trusted Signers : Self

I do not use Cloudfront and it looks like Cloudfront specifics

Is there any way to set these up (or produce an equivalent behavior) using S3 only? i.e. bucket private by default, only urls signed by one of my IAM users can be served.

Comment: You don't need to make a bucket public in order for signed URLs to work. That would entirely defeat the purpose of signed URLs.

Comment: Well, it would obfuscate the real URLs as long as there is no `list` authorization, but I get your point. However, it does not work if I remove the bucket policy (thus switching it to private).

Comment: Make sure the IAM user that you are using to generate the pre-signed URL has permissions to read from the bucket.

Comment: Not sure it would obfuscate the real URLs -- the pre-signed URL starts with the full S3 key to the object. Anyhow, as Matt indicates, the user creating the pre-signed URL needs to have read access to the bucket, otherwise there would be a very obvious privilege escalation.

Comment: I was working with my root id for the dev. But I have to apologize, because I gave a try to the CloudFront approach and it works like a charm. I read somewhere that it is cheaper than S3 so I decided to try and got an easy win. Sorry for the bother and thank you for your help. Do you think I should close the question?

Comment: Yes, you can write up an answer or simply close the question. Glad you resolved the issue. On the "CloudFront approach ... is cheaper than S3" comment, you should understand how both are priced for storage and egress, and maybe use the AWS calculator to estimate your costs.